# Двойной клик в меню

Tags: javascript

Ситуация такая: есть тема для Wordpress. В ней есть меню. Некоторые из пунктов меню имеют дочерние элементы. 
Так вот то меню, которое имеет дочерние элементы, открывается только по двойному клику мыши *(имеется ввиду, что страница, привязанная к этому пункту меню, открывается только после двойного клика)*.
Я убрал этот двойной клик:

```html
<script>
     $("li a").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    window.location.href=e.currentTarget.href;
  })
</script>
```

Все стало работать отлично. Но в мобильном виде, теперь не откроешь страницы дочерних элементов меню, потому что после того, как жмешь на основной пункт меню чтоб развернуть, открывается его страница. Как можно это это исправить. Уже голову сломал *(вот тестовый test.tehadm.ru)*...

Comment: e.preventDefault()

Comment: А можно подробнее, я к сожалению в JS полный ноль. Первый раз вообще столкнулся с ним. Спасибо.

Comment: Но ведь у вас же явно написан переход window.location.href=e.currentTarget.href;

Comment: Единственное что делает код который вы предоставили - это то, что переходит на страницу по клику на элементе ссылки. Т.е. это обычный переход по ссылке, можно вообще этот код стереть и ничего не изменится. Это искусственная имитация стандартной работы обыкновенной ссылки - переход на другую страницу и все.